# MySql returning multiple resultsets in workbench from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am using version 8 of MySql Workbench.

I have a stored procedure that return 4 results sets. When I run it in workbench it only returns the first resultset.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE getShoppingItemsRecordsets (IN ownerId INT, IN shoppingList VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM shopping_items WHERE owner_id = ownerId AND master_list = true AND shopping_list_name = 'master';
    SELECT SUM(qty * cost) AS totalCost FROM shopping_items WHERE owner_id = ownerId AND master_list = true AND shopping_list_name = 'master';
    SELECT * FROM shopping_items WHERE owner_id = ownerId AND master_list = false AND shopping_list_name = shoppingList;
    SELECT SUM(qty * cost) AS totalCost FROM shopping_items WHERE owner_id = ownerId AND master_list = false AND shopping_list_name = shoppingList;
END
```

Shouldnt it return all of them?

Malcolm

Comment: Yes it should - in separate output tabs

Comment: Well it isnt. Should be easy to see the tabs??

Comment: Why do you want to have separate outputs for such similar queries? Combine these 4 queries into one.

Comment: Should be easy to see the tabs - yes they will be called result1,result2..etc in the result grid.

Comment: For some reason the sp had only the first select in it on creation. Anyhow I have taken Akina advice and created one query. Thanks both of you .